# Lifetimes of references in mutable Vector

Tags: rust, lifetime

I have an algorithm like:

```
let seed: Foo = ...
let mut stack: Vec<&Foo> = Vec::new();
stack.push(&seed);
while let Some(next) = stack.pop {
    let more_foos: Vec<Foo> = some_function_of(next) // 0 to many Foos returned
    for foo in more_foos {
        stack.push(&foo);
    }
}
```

I receive the error that `foo` does not live long enough. I assume this is because `stack` has a greater lifetime. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`more_foos` and its contents are dropped at the end of each iteration of the `while let` loop. However, you're trying to store a reference to items from `more_foos` in `stack`, and that's not valid, as that would lead to dangling pointers.

Instead, you should make `stack` own `Foo` objects instead.

```
fn main() {
    let seed: Foo = unimplemented!();
    let mut stack: Vec<Foo> = Vec::new();
    stack.push(seed);
    while let Some(next) = stack.pop() {
        let more_foos: Vec<Foo> = unimplemented!();
        for foo in more_foos {
            stack.push(foo);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: the `for` loop can be replaced with:

```
        stack.extend(more_foos);
```

which might be slightly more efficient.